# How do I view my sqlite tables in my android app?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm working on an app that uses sqlite to store data and I need/would like to view the tables in the app to be sure things are being added correctly and the content exists. How do I review the tables and their data being used in my app.

I'm using a Nexus 7 with 4.4 on it for testing the app.

Comment: Does your tablet have root access?

Comment: For emulator only download net.cellobject.sqlitexmlbrowser_1.2.0.jar from: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3l9oD1uMtsiTWRab3JoWGt0YzQ/edit?pli=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically two choices.

1. Run the app in the emulator, then "pull" the db to your dev machine and use a tool such as SQLite Expert Personal 3 to view the db.
2. Create your db in the external storage instead of internal.  Then you can use your USB connection to "pull" the db.

I guess I can add (3): add code to dump your tables to the log file.

Comment: To be honest, I'd like to use the emulator but it seems to take way too long to load.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this can solve your problem or not but installing [THIS](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/) plugin into eclipse help me a lot to view database table and content inserted.